# Mac CPU PECI is at 104°C when encoding videos and doing heavy work

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, temperature

I monitor my MacBook's temperature using Macs Fan Control app. When I bought my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) ~2 years ago, the CPU PECI temperature is ~98°C when encoding some videos.

Now I notice that it shows 104°C when doing heavy work. I am really worried about heat damage because the T Junction rate is 105°C so is my CPU's PECI temperature supposed to be like this? Should I worry?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no need to worry.

The CPU will automatically shutdown before reaching a critical temperature that could damage the CPU. There you do not need to worry about imminent heat damage.

In addition to automatic shutdown, throttling is almost always also used before the critical temperature is reached to ensure that you avoid the shutdown.

Therefore - if you're not experiencing that the computer shuts down unexpectedly under high load, and your computer is functioning at reasonably normal speeds - there's really nothing to worry about.

I won't focus to much on the specific 105 degrees measurement. First of all the measurement software you're using might not be fully precise (PECI temperatures are always negative and an offset from critical temperature - not an absolute measurement like yours, so the software you're using must be doing a conversion), secondly the specific TjunctionMax for your CPU is calibrated individually for each CPU in the factory. So your TjunctionMax might not be 105 degrees, but rather 106 degrees or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yes you are right when I measuring my cpu temps with Intel Power Gadget it always showed the same temps as the software I am using but it never showed 100ºC in Intel Power Gadget